# NVBLAS silently fails for semi-large matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, octave, nvblas

I followed the instructions [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/drop-in-acceleration-gnu-octave/) to run octave with nvblas.  I have CUDA toolkit 7.5 installed and a tesla k40c GPU.  To start octave with nvblas, I used `LD_PRELOAD=libnvblas.so octave`.  I then ran the following simple code:

```
N = 256
A = rand(N,N)
B = rand(N,N)
A*B
```

which produces a matrix with reasonable values.  However, if I increase N to 512, or any number over 512, I get all zeros (or very small numbers) back as a result.

If I use OpenBLAS this does not happen.  The matrices should be small enough that they fit in the card's RAM (12GB).  Any idea why this might happen?

Note:  If I make A and B identity matrices this does not happen, but it still happens with A = B = ones(N,N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry the question is somewhat stale, but I tried it on an Amazon AWS EC2 p2.xlarge instance with a k80 gpu and it seems to have worked.

I was getting similar results to you (lots of zeros) when I had the default "NVBLAS_GPU_LIST 0 1" setting in nvblas.conf, which seems to refer to two GPUs, so I changed it to just one and it worked.  Complete file below:

```
#Put here the CPU BLAS fallback Library of your choice
NVBLAS_CPU_BLAS_LIB libopenblas.so

# Specify which output log file (default is stderr)
NVBLAS_LOGFILE nvblas.log

# List of GPU devices Id to participate to the computation
# By default if no GPU are listed, only device 0 will be used
NVBLAS_GPU_LIST 0
NVBLAS_AUTOPIN_MEM_ENABLED
```

Program (t1.m) slightly modified from the NVidia link, to count the number of non-zeros in the output matrix:

```
N = 16384;

# from the original NVidia example:
#A = single(rand(N,N));
#B = single(rand(N,N));

# double precision seems to work fine (not checked in detail)
A = rand(N,N);
B = rand(N,N);

start = clock();
C = A * B;
elapsedTime = etime(clock(), start);
disp(elapsedTime);
gFlops = 2*N*N*N/(elapsedTime * 1e+9);
disp(gFlops);

disp("number of elements >0:")
disp(sum(sum(C > 0)));

disp("Should be:")
disp(N*N)
```

FYI Here is the nvidia-smi output while it was running as above (it peaked at 172MiB usage with N=16384):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 0000:00:1E.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   44C    P0    80W / 149W |     80MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     21080    C   /usr/bin/octave-cli                             78MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here are the nvidia & cuda files I'd previously installed:

```
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb  
libcudnn5-dev_5.1.10-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
libcudnn5_5.1.10-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb                   
nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604_375.51-1_amd64.deb
```

I seem to get a speed up of about 8.6, with about 55 gflops from plain octave, and 478 from the GPU version.

Comment: This seems to fix it!